# NPM Workspaces only install root packages

Tags: npm, npm-workspaces

During my CI deployments I want to only install package relavent depancies required for that run.

I can do this with `npm install --workspace package-name`

However I have some root level scripts with only a handful of deps in the root package.json, how do I install just those?

npm install without a workspace flag will install everything.

I'm looking for something like:

`npm install --workspace none`

Answer (score 3):

```
npm i --workspaces=false
```

That should only install the root dependencies.

It's also possible with `npm ci`

```
npm ci --workspaces=false
```

And using the short flag `-ws`

```
npm ci -ws=false
```